# Pandas DataFrame.to_html() - formatters does not work with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem to replace date using *formatters*:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'), 'B': 3},
                      {'A': pd.Timestamp('2016-02-01'), 'B': 4}])
>>> df
           A  B
0 2016-01-01  3
1 2016-02-01  4
```

Now the question:

```
df.to_html(formatters={'A': lambda x: '???'})
```

the command above does not work (dates are unchanged), but command below works (integers are converted to '???')

```
df.to_html(formatters={'B': lambda x: '???'})
```

Does anybody knows why is that?

Comand: `df.to_html(formatters=[lambda x: '???', lambda x: '???'])` returns:

`'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>A</th>\n      <th>B</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>2016-01-01</td>\n      <td>???</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>2016-02-01</td>\n      <td>???</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'`

Comment: Your code works for me as-is. What python/pandas versions are you using?

Comment: Python 3.4.4, Pandas 0.18.0

Answer (score 0):

In earlier pandas version, formatters not work for objects with **`datetime64[ns]`** type.
In **Pandas 0.18.2**, this bug was fixed.

Reference issue of pandas in [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10690)